# Counting directories based on access

Tags: permissions, directory, access-control

I need to get the number of directories that

- Can only be read and opened by the owner of the directory.
- Can only be opened by their group.

My current solution is this:

```
ls -la . | grep "^dr-x--x---" | wc -l
```

Is this correct? Or is there a more proper way to do this?

Comment: The proper way is using `find` - check the `-type`, `-user` and `-perm` flags that allow specifying type (e.g. directory vs. file), owner and permissions, respectively. Please have a good read regarding how to use `-perm` as there are ways to find e.g. partial and exact permission matches. `find` will descend into directories, so see if you need the `-maxdepth` flag, too.

Comment: But my solution should be working too, right?

Comment: It would e.g. fail with a file containing a literal newline and your search string `filenameNEWLINEdr-x--x---` - very constructed, but it shows the limitations. `find` would allow printing one character per result and skip these problems. In general the approach could work, but as said `find` would be the "proper" way you requested. Also your way does not allow optional read access - the question is not 100% clear here, if that might be allowed.

Comment: If the code in https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/117549 looks like fun to you, then yes, but the output of `ls` wasn't meant to be parsed by computers.